# Растянуть график на весь фрейм

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.x

Создаю класс, который наследуется от Framе. В этом классе создаю `self.fig = Figure()` и через `self.fig.axes[0].plot()` рисусую график, но этот график растягивается не на весь окно(фрейм) - остаются большие поля(видимо выделенные для подписей графика). Хочу уменьшить или вообще убрать эти поля, но не нашёл в документации метода для изменения размеров этих отступов(полей). Может есть какие параметры, которые необходимо указать при создании, чтобы поля были меньше????

```
import tkinter as tk
class C(tk.Frame):
     def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)
        self.fig = Figure()
        FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.fig.canvas, self)
        self.toolbar.update()
        self.fig.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(
                side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)
        self.fig.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(
                side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)

def show(self):
       self.fig.axes[0].plot(range(len(samples)), samples)
       self.leg = ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```

Comment: Он вообще ничего не показывает. Нельзя ли опубликовать пример, который показывает не устраивающую Вас картинку (hint: у меня линукс)

Comment: Ответ: self.fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.07, bottom=0.04, top=0.97, hspace=0.13)

Answer (score 2):

Решение автора, опубликованное в комментарии:

```
self.fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.07, bottom=0.04, top=0.97, hspace=0.13)
```